# How to rewrite $f\left(x\right)=\frac{A^{2}e^{\frac{1}{2}x}+4e^{-\frac{1}{2}x}}{2A}$ in terms of hyperbolic functions

Tags: calculus, hyperbolic-functions

I was solving for the function whose surface of revolution equals the volume of the solid of revolution. I ended up with two functions $f(x)=0$ and $$f\left(x\right)=\frac{A^{2}e^{\frac{1}{2}x}+4e^{-\frac{1}{2}x}}{2A}$$ then I used desmos to evaluate the integrals of the volume and surface area of the function and they were equal. The function looks similar to the $\cosh$ function but I'm not sure how to write it in terms of a hyperbolic function.

Comment: Can you first write the definition of cosh and sinh in terms of exponentials? Then you can invert the linear system of equations to write exponentials in terms of cosh and sinh

Comment: Hint: $f$ is of the form $y+1/y=2\cosh\ln y$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo yes

Comment: @J.G. so it becomes $f(x)=2\cosh\left(\ln\left(\frac{Ae^{\frac{1}{2}x}}{2}\right)\right)$ Thanks a lot. But how do you derive this identity?

Comment: You're welcome, but you probably want to simplify that. In fact, you can write $f$ in the form $C\cosh(x/2)+S\sinh(x/2)$. In fact, you might as well skip to that with $\exp(\pm x/2)=\cosh(x/2)\pm\sinh(x/2)$.

Comment: As for how you derive $\cosh z=(\exp z+\exp-z)/2$, that's its definition.